# How to count the number of characters in a line in a csv file

Tags: java, csv, hex, converters

I have a Justice_League.csv file that has four lines with commas between them. I want to count the number of characters there are in each line and convert that number to hex.

Below is the contents of Justice_League.csv:

```
Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker                 43      2B
Oliver Queen,Green Arrow,None,Star City,Speedy,Deathstroke          50      32
Clark Kent,Superman,Flight,Metropolis,None,Lex Luthor               46      2E
Bart Allen,The Flash,Speed,Central City,Kid Flash,Professor Zoom    52      34
```

As you can see I have handcounted the characters and wrote the HEX value next to it. Now I need this done in Java. This is what I have so far. Can anybody help me out?

```
public String convertCSVToFlat (Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String csv="Justice_League.csv";
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
    String line = "";
    int count = 0;
    String str[] = new String[200];
    int[] a = new int[24];
    String[] hexNumber = new String[4];
    try {
        bReader.readLine();
        int characterSum = 0;
        int i = 0;  
        while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] f=line.split(",");
             a[count]=Integer.parseInt(f[2]);
             str[count]=f[1];            
             count++;
             characterSum += line.length();
             hexNumber[i] = Integer.toHexString(characterSum);
             i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bReader.close();
    return hexNumber.toString();
```

Comment: Can you describe what you have so far?  Does it work?  Which parts are you having trouble with?  Basically, it would be best if you have an actual question.  Not just a "do it for me please" type of question.  You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Says FileNotFoundException. Please help me fix this. So I can see if the rest of the code works.

Comment: FileNotFoundException means the file can´t be found by the program. Instead of *String csv="Justice_League.csv";*   use *String csv=full_ path_to_"Justice_League.csv"_file;* (using "File.separator" for each "/").

Comment: JuanZe, I found your advice to be helpful. But now I am getting a numberformatexception.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "None"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at com.raghav.conversion.Conversion.main(Conversion.java:25)

Comment: i don't really understand how its a "do it for me please" type of question as I have clearly pasted my code so clearly i have worked on it. you are funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the javadoc of [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). I think that you misunderstood the concept when you did this:

> String[] f=line.split(",");
>
> a[count]=Integer.parseInt(f[2]);  //--> java.lang.NumberFormatException here!

Avoid using 'magic' numbers in your code like `int[] a = new int[24];`. Why 24?

Well, here comes a version that do what you want to do. Maybe it isn't the best way to do this but it works.

```
public void convertCSVToFlat () throws Exception {
    String csv="Justice_League.csv";
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
    
    //We're storing the values at this 3 arraylists, 
    //but a better approach is using an object to hold'em
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> chars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> hex = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    String line = "";
    try {
        while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
            //I'm assuming that you don't want to count the commas and spaces.
            //If you want to, comment the next line
            line = line.replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
            int c = line.length(); //count remaining chars...
            chars.add(c);
            hex.add(Integer.toHexString(c));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bReader.close();
    
    //Just to show the results
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(lines.get(i));
        System.out.print("\t" + chars.get(i));
        System.out.println("\t" + hex.get(i));
    }
}
```

Like I said previously, this is a way to solve this. You should try another options to solve this in order to improve your knowledge...

Comment: thanks for this. i didn't even think of using the .replaceAll method.