# How to count the characters of each line in a string and convert the number to a hex

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, hex

I have this String here called message.

```
Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker
Oliver Queen,Green Arrow,None,Star City,Speedy,Deathstroke
Clark Kent,Superman,Flight,Metropolis,None,Lex Luthor
Bart Allen,The Flash,Speed,Central City,Kid Flash,Professor Zoom
```

I need to count the number of characters in each line and print them in hex.

- First line should be (From Bruce to Joker) 2b
- Second line should be (From Oliver to Deathstroke) 32
- Third line should be (From Clark to Luthor) 2e
- fourth line should be (From Bart to Zoom) 36

```java
package com.raghav.conversion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class StringToHex {
public static void Main(String[] args)   {  
    String message =    "Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker" +
                        "Oliver Queen,Green Arrow,None,Star City,Speedy,Deathstroke" +
                        "Clark Kent,Superman,Flight,Metropolis,None,Lex Luthor" + 
                        "Bart Allen,The Flash,Speed,Central City,Kid Flash,Professor Zoom";


    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> chars = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> hex = new ArrayList<String>();

    String line = "";
    int c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        lines.add(message.charAt(i), line);
        line = line.replaceAll(",", "".replaceAll(" ", ""));
        c = line.length();
        chars.add(c);
        hex.add(Integer.toHexString(c));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.size(); i++) {
        String padded = "00000000".substring(hex.size()) + hex.get(i);
        System.out.println(padded);
    }
}
```

}

This is what I have so far but I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at Line 22 `lines.add(message.charAt(i), line);`

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: For starters, you don't have any newlines in that "message"; it's all one run-on line.

Comment: You should rethink your logic. First, note that your message is one big line. There are no newlines at the end of the lines. You are not splitting it into lines. You are not counting the characters in each line. And the variable `line` contains nothing. So try planning each step and re-writing it.

Comment: The specific exception is due to your call to `add` - look at the API docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E) .. that particular call adds an element at the specified index, but your list's size starts at 0 - that call is intended for cases where there are already indices in the ArrayList - there is no need to specify the index, you can just `add(element)`, but once you get past that problem, you will discover that there are similar index problems farther down in your code.

Comment: Didn't you already ask the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782590/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-in-a-line-in-a-csv-file)?  Why didn't you edit your original question?

Comment: @sstan That does look like the same piece of code, although the error he's asking about seems to be different. Anyhow, I don't think modifying the previous question (which already has an upvoted answer) is encouraged. If you think its a dupe then flag it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Find your mistake in ` line = line.replaceAll(",", "".replaceAll(" ", ""));` by comparing the two replaceAll method calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String msg = "Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker\n" +
         "Oliver Queen,Green Arrow,None,Star City,Speedy,Deathstroke\n" +
         "Clark Kent,Superman,Flight,Metropolis,None,Lex Luthor\n" + 
         "Bart Allen,The Flash,Speed,Central City,Kid Flash,Professor Zoom";

String[] lines = msg.split("\n");
for(Integer i = 1; i <= lines.length; i++){
    int numChars = 0;
    String[] toks = lines[i - 1].split(",");
    for(String tok : toks){
        numChars += tok.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
    }
    System.out.println("Line " + i.toString() + " beginning with " + 
            toks[0] + " and ending with " + toks[toks.length - 1] + 
            " contains " + Integer.toHexString(numChars) + 
            " characters." );
}
```

This will do what you're looking for. Notice the \n at the end of each line, that makes them lines. Not sure what your second loop was for.

Answer (score 0):

Turn

`String message =    "Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker" +
                        "Oliver Queen,Green Arrow,None,Star City,Speedy,Deathstroke" +
                        "Clark Kent,Superman,Flight,Metropolis,None,Lex Luthor" + 
                        "Bart Allen,The Flash,Speed,Central City,Kid Flash,Professor Zoom";`

to

`List<String> message = new ArrayList<>();
 message.add("Bruce Wayne,Batman,None,Gotham City,Robin,The Joker");
.....`

and

`for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {`

to

`for(String line : message){`

then use `line` for the counting stuff....